# When calling a function from an instance in Python, why does the parameter 'self' need to take a string or char as an argument?

Tags: python, module, traceback

(I am new to Python, and I am not very good at OOP programming in general)

I have made Python programs before (Like maybe 6 or 7 small programs to test features), but I have always stayed in one file, i.e. making a class in that one Python file, and making a instance of it in the same file, and calling functions outside the classes scope. I never had to pass any arguments to any function that only had "self" as a parameter. But now I have this class here:
**main.py:**

```
#"main.py" is the main script of the application; The application executes this script first;#

#IMPORT FORMAT: from FILENAME import CLASSNAME
from getBoundsForApplicationUse import getBoundsForApplicationUse; #Class is part of application.#

#Variables#
connectOrCreateServer = 2 #Will be updated with users choice; 0 = choose to host/create server; 1 = choose to connect as a client to an existing server;#

#Entry Point#
getBoundsForApplicationUse_ = getBoundsForApplicationUse; #Create instance of class "getBoundsForApplicationUse"; Check top of that specific class for information;#
getBoundsForApplicationUse_.welcomeUser(''); #Welcome the user to the application in IOStream#
```

As you can see, I am creating an instance of class "getBoundsForApplicationUse" from a file named "getBoundsForApplicationUse.py" (Code for that class below), which said instance is named "getBoundsForApplicationUse_" (Notice the underscoe '_' at the rear of the instance name, class and instance name are NOT identical). From this point I am calling function "welcomeUser()", which only has 'self' as a parameter:
**getBoundsForApplicationUse.py:**

```
#"getBoundsForApplicationUse.py", will query the user, getting information on server or client connection for the IRC to connect; I.e, this script will get IP Address, Port Number, ask to start a server, ask to start a client, etc.#

class getBoundsForApplicationUse:

    #This function allows the user to choose to connect to a server, or host one; Should return value back to variable "connectOrCreateServer" in "main.py"; 0 = choose to host/create server; 1 = choose to connect as a client to an existing server;#
    def userChooseOption(self):

        return

    #This function welcomes the user to the application; Message created in IOStream#
    def welcomeUser(self):
        print("Welcome to ViprinIRC! A lightweight IRC chat!\n")
        return
```

I have to pass '', or any string of text, or else I get this error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\X-Viprin\GameCreation\AllProjects\Projects\Python\ViprinIRC\main.py", line 12, in 
getBoundsForApplicationUse_.welcomeUser(); #Welcome the user to the application in IOStream#
TypeError: getBoundsForApplicationUse.welcomeUser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

I know that the keyword 'self' is quiet similar to keyword 'this' from java. I can use 'self' to refer to class variables and methods from this class, and other classes. For example, I could make a constructor, and I could pass 3 different integer arguments to that constructor. From there, I could use the 'self' keyword, to set the recieved arguments to class variables:
"self.myClassVariableOne = myRecievedArgumentOne".
I have some idea of the self keyword, but why am I needing to pass a string to the self keyword, or is something else going one, which I am not realizing? I looked up some tutorials, and entered the error into a search engine, and had trouble finding any solution.

Could someone explain what is happening here? If you can, then thank you.

....................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
getBoundsForApplicationUse_ = getBoundsForApplicationUse; #Create instance of class "getBoundsForApplicationUse";
```

This doesn't create an instance of your class, it just creates another reference to the class itself.

You should be doing

```
getBoundsForApplicationUse_ = getBoundsForApplicationUse(); #Create instance of class "getBoundsForApplicationUse"
getBoundsForApplicationUse_.welcomeUser()
```

Once you've done this, `welcomeUser()` will receive your instance automatically as the `self` parameter.

Keep in mind, it was never necessary to pass a string in your code. Try passing 5, or an array. It will also work! This is because `welcomeUser()` is very simple and only requires you to pass **something** as `self`, but `self` would usually be expected to be an instance of the class.